# perl regex to get params string from functions

Tags: regex, perl

I have a document containing 100's of lines as show below.

```
 fn:concat(xs:float("-3.4028235E38"),xs:float("3.4028235E38"))
 fn:concat(xs:int("-1873914410"),xs:int("-2147483648"))
 fn:concat(xs:int("-1873914410"))
```

I'd like to get something like this

```
fn.concat(-3.4028235E38,3.4028235E38);
fn.concat(-1873914410,-2147483648);
fn.concat(-1873914410);
```

Thank you. Your time is appreciated!

Comment: did you mean to change `fn:concat` to `fn.concat`?

Comment: I want fn:concat() to be there, only fn:float() and fn:int() to be gone from each line

Comment: You'll notice in your original file, it has a colon in `fn:concat` where your goal has a period in `fn.concat`.  I take it that's a mistype.

Comment: sorry i overlooked the `.`. Yes I do need to convert to `fn.concat()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a quick and dirty one liner

```
perl -i -pe 's/\bxs:(?:float|int)\("(.*?)"\)/$1/g; s/(?<=\w):(?=\w)/./g;' file
```

Comment: Thank you! that works. On the side note, could you also please share the solution to get rid of the double quotes along with above regex as well?

Comment: Edited to remove double quotes as well.

Comment: Edited to translate colon to period in `fn:concat`

Comment: how to make fn:concat replacement dynamic.  Basically I'd like to replace all functions that has colon `:` to dot `.`

Comment: are they always prefixed with `fn`?

Comment: Well, I feel it may be to permissive, but I've added a solution that will do the general replacement of colons to periods for other functions.  i would prefer to make it more limiting, but I can't know how to do that without more information.